# Angularjs - One time page if user deactivates account

Tags: angularjs

I would like to implement a feature where if user deactivates his/her account it will redirect them to a one time page showing that their account has been deactivated. I want it to route a user to `www.mybusiness.com/account/deactivated` if he/she has deleted account, but I don't want this route to be directed to if a user types it in.

I would like to know he best way of implementing this. Or a source explaining how to show a page one time.

Here is my code:

`routes.js`:

```
.when('/:username/settings', {
        title:'Resonance Inn',
        controller: 'ProfileSettingsController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        templateUrl: '/static/javascripts/profiles/settings.html'
})
    .when('/:username/settings/confirm_deactivation', { //After user deletes account off this page, redirect to page for one time view showing your account has been deactivated
        title: 'Resonance Inn - We would hate to see you go...',
        controller: 'ProfileSettingsController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        templateUrl: '/static/javascripts/delete-account/delete-account.html' 
}).otherwise('/');
```

`ProfileSettingsController.js`:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module ('app.profiles.controllers')
    .controller('ProfileSettingsController', ProfileSettingsController);

ProfileSettingsController.$inject = ['$location', '$routeParams', 'Authentication', 'Profile', 'Snackbar'];

function ProfileSettingsController($location, $routeParams, Authentication, Profile, Snackbar) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.destroy = destroy;
    vm.update = update;

    activate();

    function activate() {
        var authenticatedAccount = Authentication.getAuthenticatedAccount();
        var username = $routeParams.username.substr(1);

        if (!authenticatedAccount) {
            $location.url('/');
            Snackbar.error('You are not authorized to view this page.');
        }
        else {
            if(authenticatedAccount.username !== username) {
                $location.url('/');
                Snackbar.error('You are not Authorized to view this page.');
            }
        }

        Profile.get(username).then(profileSuccessFn, profileErrorFn);

        function profileSuccessFn(data, status, headers, config) {
            vm.profile = data.data; 
        }

        function profileErrorFn(data, status, headers, config) {
            $location.url('/');
            Snackbar.error('That user does not exist.');
        }
    }

    function destroy() {
        Profile.destroy(vm.profile.username).then(profileSuccessFn, profileErrorFn);

        function profileSuccessFn(data, status, headers, config) {
            Authentication.unauthenticate();
            window.location = '/'; // I want user to be redirected to one time page...But how can I make it so you can only view it once?
            Snackbar.show('Your account has been deleted.');
        }

        function profileErrorFn(data, status, headers, config) {
            Snackbar.error(data.error);
        }
    }

    function update() {
        Profile.update(vm.profile).then(profileSuccessFn, profileErrorFn);

        function profileSuccessFn(data, status, headers, config) {
            Snackbar.show('Your profile has been updated!');
        }

        function profileErrorFn(data, status, headers, config) {
            Snackbar.error(data.error);
        }
    }
  }
})();
```

Comment: Is this page inside your angular app? Should be relatively easy to use a `resolve` on that route if it is.

Comment: @asdf_enel_hak I have added my controller and Routes so you can visualize how my setup is.

Comment: @charlietfl there is probably is a simple way of doing this. I am just unsure of how to implement it if user has deleted his account. I want it to be only shown if user has deleted his/her account. If user refreshes page or types the URL in, I want the page not to exist.

Comment: Set a variable in auth service when they deactivate. That variable must be true to access page, and as soon as they activate page toggle the variable. Use `resolve` in routing config to control access